# How are kernel states duplicated on a fork?

Tags: linux-kernel, fork, linux-device-driver

Suppose I have a character device driver in Linux that allocates some memory in the kernel to store some state against every open file descriptor.

Some process opens a fd on the driver and through some `ioctl`s the process also has provided initialization parameters for this state.

Now the process forks. All the file descriptors will also be created for the child process.

How will the fd specific state be duplicated? AFAIK `do_fork` only duplicates the data structure the kernel knows about.

Will the child process have to re-initialize the fd or it will end up sharing the state with the parent process?

Comment: is my understanding right that the states you are storing in kernel are in some memory you acquired in kernel through kmalloc in the driver ?

Comment: @yashC the state is stored in some `kmalloc`'d memory.

Comment: Then the behavior of kernel for your 'states' that has been stored in kmalloced memory will be same as it would be for other kmalloced memory. i.e. the child will get the data untouched by fork.

Comment: @yashC but now both the child and the parent will have the same pointer pointing to the same kmalloc'd memory. This essentially means that they will share the state, which might not be the intended behaviour.

Comment: intended behavior for who ? you or the kernel writers ?

Comment: @yashC for the driver writers and the processes using that driver.

Comment: In most situations when fork is used, this default behavior is a boon. If you want to get around that you can have an ioctl for resetting the flags in your kmalloced memory called by child when it is created.

Comment: @yashC no, the problem is that the state is __not__ duplicated but actually shared. Which means changes from one process will lead to changes in other. That I don't think is a boon in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No open file description state is duplicated on `fork` or `dup`. All such state will be shared between parent and child.

Comment: But that seems not like how most drivers work right? Okay, is there a way to explicitly tell a driver about a fork? So it can duplicate the state given this signal?

Comment: No they don't. Can you name an example?

Comment: @Ajay Try writing a program that opens a file and then forks. Each process waits some random time and then reads a line from the file and print it out. You will see that the file position is shared between two processes. Put differently: fork() duplicates the file descriptors, but they still refer to the same, shared open file description.